# Foreman start multiple processes?

Tags: ruby, foreman, procfile

I have three processes defined in my `Procfile`. Sometimes, I only want to run two of them. Is there a command for that?

```
$ foreman start process_1 process_2
ERROR: "foreman start" was called with arguments ["process_1", "process_2"]
Usage: "foreman start [PROCESS]"
```

Comment: maybe you should do something like: `foreman start p1` and then `foreman start p2`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the [`-c` or `--concurrency` option](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#RUNNING) and just specify the processes you want to start:

```
$ foreman start -c process_1=1,process_2=1
```

Answer (score 8):

This argument has been updated to `-m` / `--formation`

Ie: `foreman start -m "web=1,worker=1"`